Scale Provided Coordinates to a Given Image
I'm working with the Fortnite API (see here) and using their Map Locations endpoint, I can retrieve locations which include names and XYZ coordinates. The endpoint also provides a map, which returns an image URL of the map (this one).
I'm trying to use that map image with the coordinates provided to draw an X on the location on the map at the XYZ coordinates. An example of the coordinates given however:  (-78214, -70796, 112). Only using the X and Y since it's a 2D image, but those negative numbers with 5 digits aren't doing me much good on the image size I'm working with.
So I reached out to some in the Discord who've tried before and they ended up with a scaling number that I tried. Here's the code:
var mapLocations = await fortniteApi.GetFortniteMapLocations();
if (mapLocations == null)
{
    return null;
}

// Download the image
Bitmap bitmap;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    await using (var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(mapLocations.Images.Blank.AbsoluteUri))
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
}

const int worldRadius = 135000;

var stringOutput = "";
Color[] colors = [Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black, Color.Yellow, Color.Purple];
foreach (var color in colors)
{
    var namedLocations = mapLocations.POIs.Where(l => !l.Id.ToLower().Contains("unnamed")).ToList();
    var randomIndex = new Random().Next(namedLocations.Count);
    var randomLocation = namedLocations[randomIndex];

    var x = (randomLocation.Location.Y + worldRadius) / (worldRadius * 2) * bitmap.Width;
    var y = (1 - (randomLocation.Location.X + worldRadius) / (worldRadius * 2)) * bitmap.Height;

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        const int xSize = 100;
        var pen = new Pen(color, 7);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, x - xSize / 2f, y - xSize / 2f, x + xSize / 2f, y + xSize / 2f);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, x - xSize / 2f, y + xSize / 2f, x + xSize / 2f, y - xSize / 2f);
    }

    stringOutput +=
        $"{randomLocation.Name} || {color.Name} || original: ({randomLocation.Location.X} , {randomLocation.Location.Y}) || scaled: ({x} , {y})\n";

}
// Save the modified image
const string outputPath = @"C:\temp\" + "output.jpg";
bitmap.Save(outputPath);
Console.WriteLine($"Image saved to {outputPath}");

Summed up, the code picks 5 random locations and assigns them a colour and marks the X. The output looks like this. As seen in the code, this is using a scaling factor of 135000, which is arbitrary but seems to be getting me pretty close. Here's how the coordinates compare to (roughly) where they should be:
BLACK:
X: 449, 1077
should be: 489, 1184
PURPLE:
X: 893, 1038
should be: 929, 1071
BLUE:
X: 1548, 1493
should be: 1485, 1468
So ultimately, I'm wondering, is there a mathematical way to calculate the proper scale factor for this image and how to adjust the coordinates the API gives to match the proper spots on the API? I'm not sure if I need more data or not, but I figure there has to be a mathematical way to do this accurately.

l.Id.ToLower().Contains("unnamed") <-- This is inefficient. Instead, use l.Id.Contains( "unnamed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) <-- Put this outside of your foreach - not inside.

"I'm wondering, is there a mathematical way to calculate the proper scale factor for this image and how to adjust the coordinates the API gives to match the proper spots on the API?" - Yes, with a world-transform (an affine-transform) applied to the Graphics object

It looks like you're using integer division (which truncates results), which may be the reason for the errant results. Try using double for all calculations and only convert to int (Int32) right-before you pass as a parameter into Graphics's methods.

var pen = new Pen(color, 7); <-- Cache this (and eventually dispose of them) - right now your program leaks Pen resources.

Thanks for all of this feedback, applying it now. Could you elaborate more on the affline-transform and how to use that?

I can elaborate further - but you need to tell me how familiar you are with affine-transformations and matrix-math first. (StackOverflow comments are not the best venue for edification from first-principles...)

Agreed. I've had some education on matrix math, but it's been over a decade so not especially fresh in my memory.

var randomIndex = new Random().Next(namedLocations.Count); <-- You're using Random incorrectly: you need to create only a single Random object - so that all Next() values will be increasingly distant from the seed value - otherwise you'll risk creating multiple Random objects with idential seed values (due to its time-based seeding).

an affine transformation basically means, you shift every point in your image by some offset, apply some scale and perform a rotation indicated by a matrix. How you obtain that matrix depends on your source- and the destination so-called spatial reference system. There are many frameworks with coordinate-transformations out there, building that on your own is way too broad for a single answer.

Are the image's dimensions enough for the source information, or am I lacking info I'd need?

Aaah, didn't see that's a fictional world, so existing frameworks won't help you much, as the coordinate-systems will be fictional as well. So yes, you need to build your own transformation-routine.

I see yeah. Might put it out of reach if that's too complex.

Basically it's just vectorInImage = TransformationMatrix x vectorInRealWorld. So When you have five arbitrary points and know both their real-world- and their image-location, you can reverse that in order to get the matrix.

How do you know where the location should be?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain You don't need any of that - System.Drawing.Graphics has that built-in - just do something like g.ScaleTransform( (Double)135000 / bitmap.Width, (Double)135000 / bitmap.Height ).

@Dai but that assumes that 135000 value still, there's no way to determine that number from the image + coordinates?

@muttley91 My mistake, sorry; can you explain how you derived the current value of 135,000?

@Dai that's the value provided by someone who attempted scaling to the map before. As it is, it's somewhat arbitrary, and it's a bit off set in my results using it. So what I'm looking for is a way to track the correct value down, instead of that value, using the current offset that I have from the coordinates to help if that's useful.

@muttley91 I triangulated 3 points from the JSON data and they don't seem to converge on any single origin: https://i.imgur.com/4F757Db.png (note the PX coords of the 3 gold circles are based on assuming they correspond to the centre of each structure on the map - it's entirely possible the POI coords are not meant to be the structures, but are actually where the text-labels are supposed to go... in which case... panic)

@muttley91 Hmm, if I adjust my scale-factor down somewhat, then the radii do seem to converge... which suggests the Map Origin is actually not at (1024x,1024px) but actually at (1006px,1069px) - gonna try some things...

Here's my current best: https://i.imgur.com/TwlM9TT.png - it's got good convergence, but looks like I need to nudge the map origin to the south even more... (I'm using a scale-factor of exactly 0.007 btw.

I think I figured it out...
This is what you need to configure the Graphics object's world-transformation such that (for example) x: -6890, y: -75716 corresponds (roughly) to raster image coordinates x: 489, y: 1184:
using Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap( filename: @"D:\Scratch\2024-08-23 - fortnite\map.png" );

Debug.Assert( bmp.Width  == 2048 );
Debug.Assert( bmp.Height == 2048 );

using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( bmp );

g.TranslateTransform( dx: 1024, dy: 1129 ); // <-- The map origin is about 100px below the PNG image centre.

// The scaleFactor was determined by comparing the px distance from each POI to the PNG centre with the map-unit distance to the map origin.
// Originally I determined it was ~0.007365 when I incorrectly assumed the PNG Centre was also the Map Origin.
Single scaleFactor = 0.007f;

g.ScaleTransform( sx: scaleFactor, sy: scaleFactor );

g.RotateTransform( angle: -90 );
// g.ScaleTransform( 1, -1 ); // <-- I commented this out because I thought it was necessary to flip the y axis after rotating around the origin, but turns out we don't need it, but I don't know why :S

(The pertinant parts of the JSON data, btw:)
{"id":"Athena.Location.POI.Raft","name":"THE RAFT","location":{"x":-6890,"y":-75716,"z":112}},
{"id":"Athena.Location.POI.GrandGlacierHotel","name":"GRAND GLACIER","location":{"x":27536,"y":99132,"z":112}},
{"id":"Athena.Location.POI.Megalodon","name":"BRUTAL BEACHHEAD","location":{"x":-105459.99887761372,"y":-47044.00042160372,"z":2584}},
{"id":"Athena.Location.POI.DoomsCourtyard","name":"DOOM\u0027S COURTYARD","location":{"x":93844.000543,"y":52464.000694,"z":2584}},

And the below code is just rendering circles centred around 4 POIs listed in the JSON data, which immediately follows the Graphics set-up code above:
// "The Raft":
{ 
    using SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 64, baseColor: Color.Gold ) );
    FillCircleAroundPXPoint( g, b1, x: -6890, y: -75716 );
}

// "Grand Glacier"
{
    using SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 64, baseColor: Color.Blue ) );
    FillCircleAroundPXPoint( g, b1, x: 27536, y: 99132 );
}

// "BRUTAL BEACHHEAD"
{
    using SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 64, baseColor: Color.Red ) );
    FillCircleAroundPXPoint( g, b1, x: -105459.99f, y: -47044.00f );
}

// "DOOM'S COURTYARD"
{
    using SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 64, baseColor: Color.Green ) );
    FillCircleAroundPXPoint( g, b1, x: 93844.00f, y: 52464.00f );
}

static Single DistanceFromOrigin( Single x, Single y )
{
    Double hypotenuse = ( x * x ) + ( y * y );
    Single radius     = (Single)Math.Sqrt( hypotenuse ); // i.e. a circle's radius
    return radius;
}

static void FillCircleAroundPXPoint( Graphics g, SolidBrush b, Single x, Single y )
{
    Single radius = DistanceFromOrigin( x, y );

    Single topLeftX = x - radius;
    Single topLeftY = y - radius;
    
    g.FillEllipse( b, x: topLeftX, y: topLeftY, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2 );
    
    using( Pen p = new Pen( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 255, baseColor: b.Color ) ) )
    {
        g.DrawEllipse( p, x: topLeftX, y: topLeftY, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2 );
    }
    
    const Int32 dotSize = 5000;
    
    using( SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( alpha: 255, baseColor: b.Color ) ) )
    {
        g.FillEllipse( sb, x: x - (dotSize/2), y: y - (dotSize/2), width: (dotSize/2), height: (dotSize/2) );
    }
}

...which gives me this

(StackOverflow compressed my original 2048x2048px PNG upload - it's available here: https://i.imgur.com/zeqn98g.png ):

As for how I determined the scale was 0.007:

I went through the JSON data and dumped the POIs' (5-digit+) coordinates into a spreadsheet.

Because each POI's coordinate is relative to the map-origin, it means the distance between the-Origin-and-the-POI can be used to find the relative location of the Origin via triangulation (this is in map-unit-space, not PNG pixel space).

...and I found that the radii of 3 POI did not converge, which means that, simultaneously:

The origin is not at the centre of the image (because the radii did not converge at the centre).
My scale-factor is wrong (because the radii overshot each other).
That my initial rough-guess of the pixel-coordinates of the POI were wrong (because initially the radii didn't converge at all, instead of converging on a different origin located elsewhere).

(The rough-guess-pixel-locations were used to validate my results so-far)




Fortunately no iteration (i.e. trial-and-error) was necessary here:

I did make a big assumption that the POI points were meant to be positioned on the structures visible on the map - as I'm not a Fortnite player I have no idea if this is correct or not, but it works here...
I then found the radii did converge at a single location about 100px below where I thought the origin was - turns out this is the real map origin (1024px,1129px). Note that this step does not require a scale-factor yet: this is all done in map unit space, not PNG-image pixel space.
With the origin now determined, the pixel-distances between each POI and the origin can be determined (I'll admit I cheated by using Photoshop's Measure tool to save time, but it's otherwise trivial trigonometry): simply compare the map-unit-space distance from a POI to the origin (e.g. "The Raft" is 76028.84 map-units away; but ~532px PNG pixels away).

And 532 / 76028 == 0.007.






Okay this is super detailed I love it. I'm trying to adapt this to my code now and I want to make sure I understand a few things. First, your assumption that the locations should be on top of the structures on the map is correct, I should've been clearer about that.  Second, since I'm adapting the big circles to my code that draws an X right on the spot, I want to make sure I follow - the topLeftX and topLeftY, are those the points for the center of the big circle?

Alright I tried to adapt your code to drawing an X but it wasn't working, so I switched back to your circle function and it looks like I've got something wrong. Here's the image I got for The Raft (I added a black square manually for where the center should roughly be) https://imgur.com/MSZUsiB
I pushed my code up to a branch to show what it's like, I probably missed something https://github.com/rarDevelopment/replybot-dotnet/blob/61894b873a677fb219e8974b4a5d0fbf6a4bc50c/Replybot/TextCommands/GetFortniteMapLocationCommand.cs

bumping this one, any idea by chance?

@muttley91 I'm unsure what problem you say you're having...

@muttley91 "the topLeftX and topLeftY, are those the points for the center of the big circle?" - No, they're the X,Y coordinates of the top-left corner of the bounding rectangle. The centre of the rectangle would be the centre of the circle.

@muttley91 Here's my full program, it runs as-is in LinqPad 8: https://gist.github.com/daiplusplus/2f46c1e5a1a012e3a4aa7b934dc81c8f

@muttley91 All you need to do is implement this function: static void DrawCross( Graphics g, PointF centre, Single sideLength, Color color ) - ignore all of the radius stuff from my post and code because that's only relevant for finding the origin of the map's coordinate space (which has already been done) - drawing shapes on-top is the easy part.

So I don't need to subtract the radius at all from my X and Y, I just use them from the API response as-is? Because the scale was already applied?

@muttley91 Yes - that’s the whole point of my Answer post

Yeah I think what I'm missing is, I thought applying that scale factor to the Graphics object by doing g.ScaleTransform(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); would mean I could apply the same coordinates (-11173428, -10113714) and it would scale when drawn on the Graphics. But it doesn't appear to do that, since when I actually draw the X on the map, it's totally off the image.

@muttley91 Ping me here in this thread this weekend and I’ll take another look. In the meantime, where did you get that coordinate from and where is it meant to actually be on the map?

Will do. To answer that last question, I'm just pulling random named locations, so let me grab a new one. Here's the map with names on the locations https://fortnite-api.com/images/map_en.png and these are the coordinates that come back for SANDY STEPPES (at bottom left of the map): (-11173428, -10113714).
The names are a bit off, it should be centered roughly over the buildings on the map as mentioned before.

@muttley91 I took a quick look (because reasons) and I'm not seeing (-11173428, -10113714) anywhere in the fortnite-api.com/v1/map.json data - instead it gives the coords of "Sandy Steppes" as -78214,-70796.

I see what happened there, those values are when I did x / scaleFactor (so -78214 / 0.007). The values you listed second are correct. But even when I don't divide by scaleFactor, I still don't get my X anywhere on the map. Updated my code on my branch here for next time you're able to look.
I also notice the TranslateTransform in your code in post uses dx: 1024, but in the link you posted it's dx: 1028.

tagging for the weekend :) @Dai

@muttley91 Please edit your program so that it uses hardcoded coordinates and doesn't use any externally-loaded resources (besides the map image) - nor any calls to Random - so that I can reproduce it at my end.

done, code branch linked above is updated. I just replaced the point with the hard-coded value for SANDY STEPPES. (The random code is technically still in there but unused since I hard-code the point value)

The previous code link seems to have been a permalink, so here's a link to the correct updated file

@muttley91 It looks like the real problem was just that you were using a Pen width that was too narrow to see (and xSize should be 1000 not 100) - when I bump it up to 7000 it's visible: https://imgur.com/a/LCL7Wqw

That did it! I had to mess with the xSize amount even more, I think because of the scale I'm working with here now, but that worked. Thanks for all of your help!

@muttley91 Phew!

Though when I tried to launch this code, turns out this usage of GDI+ won't work because I'm pushing it to a Linux box, so I'll have to use SkiaSharp. On my way to the next problem to solve! :)

As the map changes between seasons (same URL linked in my original post fwiw), it messed up these calculations. I'm wondering first, do you remember how you came to get the values of g.TranslateTransform( dx: 1024, dy: 1129 ); in the original code?

@muttley91 Yes, by choosing 3 known points on the map and seeing where their radii converge, which will be the map origin.
